# Why am I missing in converting the dates to factor?

Tags: r, zoo, strptime, as.date

my data with 2 columns looks like this:

[image: My data look like this]

I am trying to convert the date (factor) into date.

I have tried so many tricks and techniques and essentially none of them are working. Can you see what I am doing wrong? Please see my various attempts below:

```js
##Attempt 1
#variation 1
dec18Apr20$date <- as.Date(dec18Apr20$date, format = "%m/%d/%y" )
#variation 2
dec18Apr20$date <- as.Date(dec18Apr20$date, "%m/%d/%y" )
#variation 3
dec18Apr20$date <- as.Date(dec18Apr20$date, "%y/%d/%m" )
#variation 4
dec18Apr20$date <- data.frame(as.Date(dec18Apr20$date, format = "%m/%d/%y" ))
#variation 5
dec18Apr20$date <- as.Date(factor(dec18Apr20$date, format = "%m/%d/%y" ))
#Variation 6
dec18Apr20$date <- as.Date(factor(dec18Apr20$date, "%m/%d/%y" ))
#variation 7
dec18Apr20$date <- as.Date(dec18Apr20$date, "%y/%d/%m" )

##Attmpt 2
strptime(dec18Apr20$date, "%m/%d/%y")

##Attemp 3 
#variation 1
mdy(as.character(dec18Apr20$date))
#variation 2
mdy(dec18Apr20$date)


##Attempt 4
parse_date_time(dec18Apr20$date, "dmy")


##Attempt 5
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(dec18Apr20$date))
```

UPDATE: output for dput(head(dec18Apr20)) is as follow:

[image: Output for dput()]

Comment: `dec18Apr20$date <- as.Date(as.character(dec18Apr20$date), format = "%m/%d/%y" )` should work!

Comment: @Duck It works even if `date` is a factor, try `as.Date(factor(c("12/01/2018", "12/02/2018")), "%m/%d/%Y")`. **To the OP:** Can you post data in dput format? Edit the question with the output of `dput(head(dec18Apr20))`, please, in order for us to have a copy of the internal representation of your data.

Comment: @Duck I think Rui has it right here with the capital `Y` since it is full years rather than 2-digit years

Comment: @Duck thanks for your comments. Doesn't work unfortunately. Results as below '  dec18Apr20
        time       date
1   00:01:02 2020-12-01
2   00:05:32 2020-12-01
3   00:16:18 2020-12-01
4   00:19:18 2020-12-01
5   00:20:54 2020-12-01
6   00:25:32 2020-12-01
7   00:25:53 2020-12-01
8   00:26:23 2020-12-01
9   00:27:12 2020-12-01
10  00:27:15 2020-12-01
11  00:27:33 2020-12-01
12  00:29:05 2020-12-01
13  00:33:54 2020-12-01
14  00:34:05 2020-12-01
15  00:35:57 2020-12-01
16  00:38:49 2020-12-01
17  00:41:07 2020-12-01'

Comment: The `lubridate` package (part of `tidyverse`) makes date handling much easier

Comment: @AllanCameron You are right sir! This should work `dec18Apr20$date <- as.Date(as.character(dec18Apr20$date), format = "%m/%d/%Y" )`

Comment: @RuiBarradas updated with output.

Comment: you are posting IMAGES. DO NOT do this. When asked to post the output, you are required to copy paste it here. Not to post the images

Comment: thank you @Duck and Allan C . it worked with a capital Y. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

As one of the commentators pointed out, I need to have a capital `Y` in the `format = "%m/%d/%Y"`. The code below worked for me.

```
dec18Apr20$date <- as.Date(as.character(dec18Apr20$date), format = "%m/%d/%Y" )
```